# Step wise function in R stays idle after running LM model

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to run stepwise to reduce useless features over my LM model, which contains near 70 columns ( most dummy ones).
issue command "step_FULL <- step(modelo_DB_Reg_Linear, k = 3.841459)" and R Studio stays there forever...I have also tried MASS function and same happens.

here the model command and Summary output after which I try to run stepwise:

```
modelo_DB_Reg_Linear <- lm(formula = dif_saida_minutos ~ . , data = DB_Reg_Linear)
```

I would try to add the summary output here but app was insisting my text was off limits and I just could not fix.

Comment: What is `find("step")` ?  How many rows does your data set have?  How long does it take to fit the initial model?

Comment: the model fir is quite fast ~ 10 seconds...databse has 300K lines, however i tried running it all with 5% and even 1% of it...and same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably collapse dummy variables into factor variables to reduce the true number of available specifications -- obviously, this does not change the design matrix, but the `step()` function should not be considering models with some but not all of the dummy variables representing one true factor regressor.

Also, try running with the `trace` argument in `step()` so that information is printed (set it to a positive number, higher prints out more information).